# Property Owner is not available for Database 'DBNAME'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> Property Owner is not available for Database 'DBNAME'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I am getting this error when trying to 'right click' a properties on the database.
Does anyone know how to fix this ?

I've tried following:

```
use DBNAME
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'myUser'
```

Getting the following message:

> The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database.

Any Ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: SQL 2000:

EXEC MyDatabase..sp_changedbowner ‘sa’;

SQL 2005 and SQL 2008

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDatabase to sa;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myUser` is probably already a database user.  You shoudl be passing a login principal to the stored procedure.  Do something like this:

```
use DBNAME
go

exec sp_changedbowner 'myLoginThatShouldBeDBO'
go
```